# mkdir is not working on Android P same code working till 7.0

Tags: android, kotlin

Would like to create and directory on SDCard in 9.0, the same code is working in <9.0 where as in 9.0 its failing below is the code snippet.

The same code is working fine in till 7.0.

```
            val dir = File(apkLocation)
            if(!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir()
            }
            return if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory) {
                fileLocation
            } else null
```

Result is null above

Comment: if you are trying to make, read, write directory or file in private storage like in `data/data` of some other app it will not let you do, only directory or file that you can access from your app in private storage is `data/data/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Intention is to not to create in /data/data it should be on SDCard/ExternalDir..  Moreover it is working as expected in  <=7.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted on that device, to operate on storage

```
val code = context.getPackageManager().checkPermission(
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    context.getPackageName()
)

if (code == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO create directory
} else {
    // TODO reqeust permission and serve on result
}
```

You can find more on requesting permission on:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html